# converting text file into json format

Tags: python

I have a file in format:

```
{ 'name':50,
  'ntokens':12345,
  'values':[ 
             [
              ["abc" , 1234],
              ["foo" , 12234]
             ],
             [ 
              ["foobar",483]
             ]
          ]

}
```

I want to hammer this file into this format:

```
{ 
  { "name":"cluster 1",
     "children": [ 
               {"name": "abc","size":1234},
               {"name": "foo","size":12234}
              ]
  },
  { "name":"cluster 2",
     "children": [ 
               {"name": "foobar" ,"size":483}
              ]
   }
}
```

My attempt has been very fragile. :(

I am reading thru file and creating bunch of regex rules. Not being able to get my head around.

I am almost sure there should be a pythnoic way (maybe json??) to resolve this?

Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: load the data with `ast.literal_eval` or `yaml` if that's what they are and then change the elements like you would do with a normal python dictionary. In the end you may use `json.dump` to save it to a file.

Comment: Are `[]` instead of `{}` in `["abc":1234]` a typo?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: No its the right format...its a list

Comment: @JBernardo: Gimme a sec :). but i think you are not going to read it.. its a lot of if else if else.. with manual regex rules defined.. but let me bit make in anonmyzed before posting it :)

Comment: It's hard. The problem with most of these parsers is they expect in certain format. Most of them requires strict formating. Did you get this json file from somewhere.

Comment: Yes.. The first one is json output at c++ end from an already existing  code.. and I am transfering that file using socket at python end.. but my python code is compatible with second format :(

Comment: The first one is not JSON, it's something sort of like JSON. If you have some documentation on what the _actual_ sort-of-JSON-like language is, you can get/write a parser for it; otherwise, you're in for some tag-soup-style hacking fun. Or… can you modify the C++ code? If so, make it actually generate JSON (or YAML or something else that you already have a parser for).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Hi.. sorry there was a typo.. its a tuple..

Comment: @CppLearner: Hi there was a typo.. do you think its solvable now?

Comment: if you add a comma after 12345, you could use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://ideone.com/NYhMis) as @JBernardo suggested.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Thanks. yeah there is a comma.. so sorry to all for making so many typos.